# ClassNotFound Exception when using arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, exception

Hello! I'm trying to create a chunk of java which allows me to call classes depending on strings called from an array - however, I can't seem to get it to work, unfortunately. If anyone could help I'd be most grateful, I've included the code I've hashed out so far...

```
public class ProcrastinatorPanel extends JPanel {

    String[] room = {
             "Hallway", "Bathroom", "Study", 
             "Bedroom", "Dining Room", "Living Room", 
             "Kitchen", "Playroom", "Bathroom", "Garage" };

    int roomNumber = 0;

    public ProcrastinatorPanel() {

        Hallway.hallway = new Hallway();
        Class roomClass = Class.forName(room[roomNumber]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `Hallway`?

Comment: You have no class named `Hallway` that the classloader can find (which in this case means it's not in the default package). Use the fully qualified name.

Comment: This is what's bothering me - the class named Hallway exists, and is in the same source folder...

Comment: Does `Hallway.hallway = new Hallway();` need to be this: `Hallway hallway = new Hallway();`

Comment: `Hallway` needs to be in the discouraged default package. Or you need to specify a package name.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Not necessarily, `hallway` could be a static field of `Hallway`.

Comment: They're both currently in the default package

Comment: @arshajii doesn't it have to be a static field?

Comment: @SteveP. Yes, for the code to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Class.forName()` method to work you need to pass it a string representing a fully qualified Class name. E.g. `"com.mycompany.main.Hallway"`

You could also try making an array of `Class`es instead of an array of strings. To get you started, the expression `Hallway.class` will evaluate to the Hallway class

Also as professionalamateur pointed out `Hallway.hallway = new Hallway()` is not going to work. The code should read `Hallway hallway = new Hallway()`. `Hallway` is the type of the variable and `hallway` is the name.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to place classes into arrays - what would you define the type as?

Comment: @user2479645 That's a good question, I never use arrays. Just Class I would imagine. I'm sure Class<?> wouldn't work. You could also of course declare a Set of classes (e.g. HashSet<Class> or HashSet<Class<?>>) or an ArrayList or something

Comment: @Accipheran, the way the user has it written, `Hallway.hallway` represents a `static` field, `hallway` in `Hallway`.  Whether or not this is intentional is up for debate, but it CAN definitely work.

Comment: @SteveP. yea that's good a point. I just assumed because of the nature of the question that the OPs intentions were to just declare a variable hallway and set it to a new Hallway

Comment: @Accipheran that's a good assumption, but I just wanted to clarify that it is potentially valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName() would require full qualified class name.

Also I did not see any catch/throw of ClassNotFoundException exception. Is the code you mentioned complete?